# How to have separate images for radio buttons - HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two radio buttons on my HTML form. I want one button to look like a male and the other button to look like a female. Currently I can only make the buttons look like males. I can not let them have their own background images, they can only share images. Here is my HTML code,

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="i_am"/>
<label for="radio1"></label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="i_am"/>
<label for="radio2"></label>
```

This is the code for my CSS,

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
   background:url(../images/people.png) 0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

How can I make radio1 have the background of a male, and radio2 have a background of a female.

Currently my code only makes the radio buttons look like males. I need to know how they can have separate background images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have used the attribute selector – just expand that on to the labels. Add a separate statement for each label with a different image:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: top center;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label[for="radio1"] {
    background-image: url("../images/male.png");
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label[for="radio2"] {
    background-image: url("../images/female.png");
}
```

Tip: Use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) instead of single images for a little loading performance speedup.